# Script not working in admin footer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

The weird problem I am facing is that the hl_admin_script wont load in footer. But it load work when I change the **$in_footer** to **false**

```
/*
    Load Admin Scripts only on custom-post-type post type.
*/
function hl_enqueue_admin() {
    global $post;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->post_type !== 'custom-post-type') {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hl_jquery-ui', plugins_url( 'css/hl-jquery-ui.css', __FILE__ ) , array(), '1.0.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hl_admin_script', plugins_url( '/js/hl_admin_script.js', __FILE__ ) , array('jquery','jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-sortable','jquery-ui-accordion'), '2.0.0', true );
    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'hl_admin_script', 'ajax_object',
         array( 
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
            'post_id' => $post->ID,
         ));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hl_enqueue_admin' ,1000 ,0 );
```

Comment: Can you change AJAX async to false? Probably it makes a problem but I don't know what is inside the hl_admin_script

Comment: How could I change that?

Comment: when you put in_footer to false where does it loads? in the footer?

Comment: It loads in the head section. Before the <body></body> tag.

Comment: @patwoj98 Even if I remove all the contents from the hl_admin_script file it still does not load..